# Check that a given path points to a file under a certain subfolder

Tags: java, path

I get, as input from the user, a path to a certain file.

The user is allowed to access this file, only if the file is inside a certain parent-folder "User/".

For example:

- "User/1/2/3" is good.
- "User/1/../2" is good.
- "User/1/../../2" is not good (goes outside "User/" folder).
- "Parent/../User/1/2/3" is good.

Is there a simple way to check this in Java?

Comment: Maybe `normalize` followed by `startsWith`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Comment: @RC Yes, why not post as answer?

Comment: @MarkusBenko because it's a *vague idea* not an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about:-

```
boolean allowed = new File("the/path").getCanonicalPath().contains("User/");
```

Comment: why "contains" and not "startsWith"?

Comment: As per your example, "Parent/../User/1/2/3" should return true, but doesn't start with "User/".  `getCanonicalPath()` returns the full path, so it will be something like "c:\folder\User"..

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) from the given pathname and loop over the [`File#getParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent()) chain:

```
public boolean check(final String pathname) throws IOException {
    for(File target = new File(pathname).getCanonicalFile();
        null != target;
        target = target.getParentFile()) {

        if("User".equals(target.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just remember to resolve the given pathname using `File#getCanonicalFile()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`File#getCanonicalPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()). Below you can find an excerpt of its Javadoc.

> Returns the canonical pathname string of this abstract pathname. A
>   canonical pathname is both absolute and unique. The precise definition
>   of canonical form is system-dependent. This method first converts this
>   pathname to absolute form if necessary, as if by invoking the
>   getAbsolutePath() method, and then maps it to its unique form in a
>   system-dependent way. **This typically involves removing redundant names
>   such as "." and ".." from the pathname**, resolving symbolic links (on
>   UNIX platforms), and converting drive letters to a standard case (on
>   Microsoft Windows platforms).